# Satisfying monad laws without a type constructor

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, category-theory

Given e.g. a type like

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Leaf a
```

I can easily write instances for Functor, Applicative, Monad, etc.

But if the "contained" type is predetermined, e.g.

```
data StringTree = Branch StringTree StringTree
                | Leaf String
```

I lose the ability to write these instances.

If I were to write functions for my StringTree type

```
stringTreeReturn :: String -> StringTree
stringTreeBind   :: String -> (String -> StringTree) -> StringTree
stringTreeFail   :: String -> StringTree
-- etc.
```

that satisfied the monad laws, could I still say that `StringTree` is a monad?

Comment: What would `fmap (const ())` result in?

Comment: You might even do `stringTreeFMap :: (String -> String) -> (StringTree -> StringTree)`, but to really be a monad in the sense of category theory you need `join :: m (m a) -> m a`, which doesn't fit at all.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you just define: `type StringTree = Tree String`?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: I can; this was a purely theoretical question.

Comment: You cannot write a `Monad` instance for `StringTree`, but I do believe that you could still use `do` sugar by using the `RebindableSyntax` language extension.

Comment: Incidentally, from a theoretical point of view: this structure is a relative monad (http://cs.ioc.ee/~james/papers/Relative_Monads.pdf)  whose source category is the singleton category with the single object String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You're looking at the difference between a *type* and a *kind*. Simplistically, a kind is the way that Haskell classifies types, so it's a level of abstraction above types. `ghci` can help.

```haskell
:type stringReturn
stringReturn :: String -> StringTree
:type Functor
<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `Functor'
```

So right off the bat, we can see that a function, which has a type, is an entirely different thing than a type, which has a kind.

We can also ask `ghci` about kinds.

```haskell
:kind Functor
Functor (* -> *) -> Constraint
:kind StringTree
StringTree :: *
:kind Tree
Tree :: * -> *
```

Kinds use `*` for variables in their notation. We can see from the interaction above that `Functor` expects a type that is parameterized over one argument. We can also see that `StringTree` doesn't take any parameters, and `Tree` takes one.

That's a long way of expressing and unpacking your question, but hopefully it shows the difference between types and kinds.

Comment: Section "[Type Classes and Overloading](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html)" from "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell, Version 98" briefly introduces _kind_, if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`Tree a` isn't a monad, either generally or for any particular `a`, `Tree` **itself** is a monad. A monad isn't a type, it's a correspondence between *any* type and a "monadic version"  that type. For example, `Integer` is the type of integers, and `Maybe Integer` is the type of integers in the `Maybe` monad.

Consequently, `StringTree`, which is a type, can't be a monad. It's just not the same kind of thing. You can try to imagine it as the type of strings in a monad, but your functions `stringTreeReturn`, etc, don't match the types of their monadic correspondents. Look at the type of `>>=` in the `Maybe` monad:

```
Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

The second argument is a function from some `a` to **any** type in the `Maybe` monad (`Maybe b`). `stringTreeBind` has the type:

```
String -> (String -> StringTree) -> StringTree
```

The second argument can only be a function from `String` to the monadic version of `String`, rather than to the monadic version of any type.

Consequently, you can't do everything you can do to values in an arbitrary monadic type to `StringTree` values, which is why it can't be made an instance. Even if you could somehow get it treated as a monad, things would start going wrong when generic monadic code expects to be able to use generic monadic operations in ways that don't make sense for `StringTree`.

Ultimately, if you're thinking of it as "like" a monad because it's `String` in a container that can behave similarly to monadic containers, the easiest thing to do is simply make it a generic container of any type (`Tree a`). If you need have auxiliary functionality that depends specifically on it being a tree of strings, then you can write that code as operating only on `Tree String` values, and it will happily co-exist along with code that works generically on `Tree a`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that wouldn't be a monad. Think about it, can you write a monad `m` so only `m String` is ever possible?